# Development process to work on React js Project

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, workflow, development-environment

We are going to start new project in React very soon. Multiple teams are going to work on the diffrent modules of same project. We have background of working on PHP projects and we used to make changes in files and push it on development server using FTP.

But in react we have to transpile the code whenever we make single line of change. This is not an issue if a single developer working on it’s local machines as there are so any options available like Webpack's hot reload.

How can a team work on React app without wasting its time on compiling and building application everytime to see changes in action? Can you suggest us any tool? We are going to use AWS services too, is there any option avilable for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

The compilation runs locally on each developer's machine. So is not really an issue. Developers run the environment on their machines and have whatever transpiler you want to use running so that every change made on a source file creates the compiled files as well. When they want to "push" the changes then they just upload the source files to your FTP server.

But on the server, you will need to set up a transpiler (it could be the same your developers use) so that whenever the FTP server receives new code it runs the transpiler on the files as well. This is done automatically by the transpiler process if it is set up to do so and it usually happens very fast (a slow transpiling process is rare unless you are doing something very special)

In general, when using Git (which I would recommend you to do), every developer runs the transpiler locally and just pushes the changes on the source files. When a "deploy" on the dev/staging server is required, they just run a command that builds/transpiles everything and pushes a single compiled file that have all the source files transpiled and "bundled" in it. The server then just loads the bundled files and ignores completely the source files.

I suggest you to check the project https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app which kinds of reflects my last paragraph, is very easy to have a multideveloper environment running and "pushable" to Heroku or other servers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It really helped me. We are going to follow the same